# Invalid xmlns:xdt schema URL in web.config

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-config, schema, web-config-transform

I'm using a nuget package that added `xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"` into the `configuration` node of my web.config, which caused my application to break. I resolved this by reverting to a previous version of the package, but I decided to try to navigate to the URL http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform only to discover that it's an invalid URL.

Now, I know almost nothing about XML... but this doesn't seem right. Did Microsoft recently move this resource? If so, does that break applications that use it? Also, is there a standard procedure when it comes to dealing with invalid schema URLs?